# Hadoop/Cascading: How to flatten result?

Tags: hadoop, cascading

I don't know whether the normalize is a correct word, please edited my question with correct word if you know.

I have unstructured data, which I have already processed, and resulted in data like below.

```
id | group | count
-------------------
1  |   A   | 32
1  |   B   | 1213
1  |   C   | 12
2  |   B   | 12
2  |   C   | 1
3  |   A   | 32
3  |   B   | 1213
3  |   C   | 12
```

Can I continue processing the data and make it resulted like below?

```
id | A  |  B   | C
-------------------
1  | 32 | 1213 |12
3  | 32 | 1213 |12
2  | 0  |  12  | 1
```

*Edited:*

I am able to use something like below to make the data *almost* resulted in what I want:

```
Pipe conclusionPipe = new Pipe("conclusionPipe",countPipe);
conclusionPipe = new GroupBy(conclusionPipe, new Fields("id"), new Fields("group"));
conclusionPipe = new Every(conclusionPipe, new Fields("group", "count"),new CustomAggregator(), Fields.RESULTS);
```

And the `CustomAggregator` class:

```
public static class Context implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7038915614929335060L;
    Map<String, Long> counter = new HashMap<String, Long>();
    void add(String key, Long value) {
        Long val = counter.get(key);
        if (val == null) val = 0L;
        counter.put(key, value+val);
    }
    Long get(String key) {
        return counter.get(key);
    }
}
@Override
public void start(FlowProcess flowProcess,
        AggregatorCall<Context> aggregatorCall) {
    aggregatorCall.setContext(new Context());
}

@Override
public void aggregate(FlowProcess flowProcess,
        AggregatorCall<Context> aggregatorCall) {
    aggregatorCall.getContext().add(aggregatorCall.getArguments().getString(0), aggregatorCall.getArguments().getLong(1));

}

@Override
public void complete(FlowProcess flowProcess,
        AggregatorCall<Context> aggregatorCall) {
    Set<String> keySet = aggregatorCall.getContext().counter.keySet();
    Fields field = new Fields();
    field = field.append(aggregatorCall.getGroup().getFields());
    Tuple result = new Tuple(aggregatorCall.getGroup().getTuple());

    field = field.append(new Fields(keySet.toArray(new Comparable[keySet.size()])));
    aggregatorCall.getOutputCollector().setFields(field);
    for (String key:keySet) {
        result.add(aggregatorCall.getContext().get(key));
    }

    aggregatorCall.getOutputCollector().add(result);
}
```

And have output Tap like below:

```
Tap outTap = new Hfs(new TextDelimited(true, "\t"), "out");
```

Where it have headers declared.

The result is something like below:

```
---empty line----
1  | 32 | 1213 |12
3  | 32 | 1213 |12
2  | 12 |   1
```

The problem is, each row doesn't know what is the header, and each row may have different header. Is there any way to make each row know what header for each column? It's also ok to make each row that doesn't have specific header have value of zero. But it would better to group each row with same header, e.g:

```
id | A  |   B  | C
1  | 32 | 1213 |12
3  | 32 | 1213 |12
id | B  |   C
2  | 12 |   1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. You can do this using MapReduce or you want to use something else ??

Comment: you might want to take a look at [`GroupBy`](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.2/javadoc/cascading/pipe/GroupBy.html) pipe and cascading tutorials.

Comment: @addicted20015 @soulcheck I'm currently using Cascading. And it's part of the process. Based on my understanding, `GroupBy` will group the input based on `groupFields`, and it can only process the `groupFields`. In my case the `groupFields` will be id, no? What kind of `Aggregator` that can transform the input to specified result?

Comment: @dieend Yes, in your case `groupFields` would be id, and `sortFields` would be 'group'. Then you'd use your own custom Aggregator to put the grouped and sorted values to a single tuple.

Comment: @soulcheck I've updated my question, could you take a look at it?